# Client isn't receiving emails from my web form, but I can

Tags: email, shared-hosting, email-accounts

I've got some generic contact forms on my clients website. When I test them I can send them to my email address (and my gmail account and my work mates addresses) successfully, but the client claims they are not receiving them at all (did have them check the spam folder - nothing there).

CPanel doesnt show any errors and if I use the Track Delivery tool it says it works fine.

This is a LAMP stack shared server environment.

I am using the PHP mail function to send.

Running an MX check on the site reveals nothing unordinary.

There are no errors in the error log.

Would anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Are there any bounces? What is the clients email? If its something like `@yahoo` (or att+aol and friends) you need to make sure the form is sending with the app email as the "From" with that `@yahoo` in the reply/envelope mechanisms. Yahoo blocks mail originating from an `@yahoo` address unless it was sent through the yahoo interface. We experienced this on quite a few contact forms. Doesn't happen with gmail and other addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Cpanel issue.

Go to Cpanel > open MX records > select Domain in Question > Make sure "Remote Mail Exchanger" is selected.